# AWS glue spark submit use Spark avro

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, pyspark, aws-glue, aws-glue-spark

How to specify/pass packages parameters to the AWS glue spark job?

I am using [Glue version 1](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/release-notes.html) which supports [Spark 2.4.3](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-avro.html) and want to use Spark avro to read some avro files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot provide the package option to the glue jobs instead download the dependent jars from maven repository

Then place those jars in s3 and pass them as additional jars to your job.
This way you can access those jars within the job.

For `spark2.4.3` you need to pass this jar

https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/spark/spark-avro_2.12/2.4.3/spark-avro_2.12-2.4.3.jar